# Retrieve viable option paths from Windows Work Flow into the client?

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4

1) Once I've bookmarked a particular point in a work flow is there a way for a client to ask the work flow where it is at and retrieve its viable options? So like lets say I have 5 buttons labeled 1 through 5... If I I'm in step 3 I have the option of going to step 4 or step 5... I want the ability for the client to ask the work flow where I'm allowed to go next... The work flow would say these are your options and based on that the client would show buttons 4 and 5 and everything else would be greyed out... I guess in work flow terminology if the work flow is say at a pick waiting for a trigger is there some way the client can be informed of the available pick options....

2) is there any native support for roles that I could also integrate with this? So user account manager can click 4 or 5 but call center can only click 5.

Basically I have a work flow that needs to model a process (obviously) and this process is managed at each stage by different departments in the company. But at certain points in the work flow an account manager could be allowed to transition the work flow in 2 or 3 directions where as a call center rep is only allowed to transition it in one direction.... But I need a way for our call center client to ask the work flow what stage something is in and what the user logged in is allowed to do and then based on that the client software will present them with what options they have....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using workflow persistence there is a column that contains the current named bookmarks the workflow can have resumed. I have used this in applications to drive the UI. It you are using workflow services and the Receive activity you will find the SOAP action as the bookmark name.

Comment: That's good to note for discovering where I am.. I'd still like to know where I can go. At that point would my only option be to iterate over the instance and find the activities coming afterwards? or can I query it somehow for all activities connected after the bookmark?

Comment: The bookmarks are **not** about where you in the workflow are but what you can do. For example if there is a Pick activity waiting for any one of three WCF messages you can see the possible SOAP actions from the bookmarks.

Comment: oh ok I'm following you now. I'll tinker around with that for a bit see if that fits what I'm trying to do. Still not totally positive how I'll integrate that with user roles... I know you can restrict services through role providers maybe that will do what I need... Thanks for the reply